# Windows screen scale messing up css sizes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css

Having a weird issue, on Windows 10 in the screen settings on some laptops the default value (the recommended) is 125% so when opening a web page everything is to big because the page was build for 100%

How this can be handled? css? JS? 
honestly don't know how to approach this

Details:

- Web app built with React.
- In 100% everything is scaled correctly
- From the problematic laptop other websites are scaled correctly (with
  the settings on 125%)
- Problematic laptop (don't know if this is relevant) `Lenevo yoga 730 15inch`

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "handling this"? You will have similar issues on other high-resulution displays. In css you will have to add special rules using the mediaqueries (min/max-resolution, min/max-device-pixel-ratio) and in javascript you will have to multiply your size/positions by window.devicePixelRatio to get the "real" pixel position

Comment: Too much use of `px` unit, maybe. Use `em` or `rem` instead.

Comment: I don't think its a resolution issue. by "handling this" I mean create a solution that will keep same scale in the described situation

Comment: this windows "feature" is a complete misunderstanding and messes websites' layout badly. Especially that 1920x1080 resolution is not a rare thing for modern 14'' screens anymore, and "recommended" scale is 150% [sigh]

Answer (score 19):

In CSS you can use (not standard yet):

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25) { ... }
```

and

`@media (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25) { ... }`

**Note from 2024:** you can now use the `resolution` property:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/resolution

```
/* Minimum resolution */
@media (min-resolution: 1.25dppx) {
/* Maximum resolution */
@media (max-resolution: 1.25dppx) {
```

In Javascript you can use:

`window.devicePixelRatio > 1.25 ? doA() : doB()`

Reference:

[-webkit-device-pixel-ratio - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-webkit-device-pixel-ratio)

[Window.devicePixelRatio - Web API インターフェイス | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio)

Comment: Thanks I will test this and let you know

Comment: this works for me although how can we handle the if user zooms the page to 125 percent on top of 125 percent setting in windows ?

Comment: sorry for the late feedback, but Ive implemented it and it worked like a charm - thank you

Answer (score 8):

You might try to add a viewport meta tag in the head section of your index.html:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Comment: I don't think this can solve the problem

Answer (score 4):

You could use CSS resolution for this

```
/* Exact resolution */
@media (resolution: 150dpi) {
  p {
    color: red;
  }
}

/* Minimum resolution */
@media (min-resolution: 72dpi) {
  p {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
}

/* Maximum resolution */
@media (max-resolution: 300dpi) {
  p {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```